# Can't boot after updating OS update on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, boot, grub, error-handling, software-updates

I'm using CentOS 7 with gnome UI

After I use software update tool and `install&restart` the `OS update` it can't boot, it can go through the pass phase for the disk but keep spinning and can't access the login page.

I've also boot from my installer and goto troubleshooting>rescuer a CentOS and tried the first and second method but still can't boot

P.S. After I enter rescuer mode with my installer I run the following command

```
cd /
ls -f
```

And it didn't show a directory call home so I'm worry is this issue causing the OS can't boot?

Answer (score 1):

You have to mount your main filesystem with he `mount` command to reach your home again since you're in rescue mode.

However, this is not what's preventing you to boot, something probably went wrong with your system update.

CentOS is not that prone to have such issue though.

If you did install something that wasn't supposed to be, like a special .rpm or throught a special repository, that's where your issue is.

Comment: Sorry sir, I think we got a wrong point, I just point out I'm wondering if it causes the **issue** and my issue is CentOS can't boot.

Comment: Updated my answer, this is not the cause of your issue.

Comment: but the issue still not solved yet...

Comment: Then should I reinstall the whole CentOS? Also I remeber I got to a terminal like screen on my first boot after update, It is showing that it's updating other package (like chrome) but it stops at a point which said a.... (can't remember) stop working and then just stop there. Also for the later reboot, as it's spinning before going to login page it sometimes (once per boot) switch to a terminal like place (black background) for miliseconds

Comment: @X.LINK: one common issue is that updating kernel packages does not roll back if you run out of space on `/boot`. Lesson: don't run out of space on `/boot`, `package-cleanup --oldkernels` is your friend.

Comment: Since Mnincial apparently can't boot, he'll have to do that in single user mode: https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Installation_Guide-en-US/s1-rescuemode-booting-single.html

But that would be very surprising not to have enough disk space for /boot if everything was taken care of by CentOS installer.

Besides, if a kernel update really screwed up, I wouldn't remove the old kernel for safety reasons, but the newer one first.

Then, let Mununcial see if he has enough space on /boot with Gparted for example.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz So should I enter the terminal and type the command you provide by the installer?

Comment: @X.LINK Also how can I know if I got enough space since I can't access it and can't mount it on Windows

Comment: Please follow the tutorial to go into single user mode, and tell if managed to do it so we can tell you how to know if you have enough space on /boot

Comment: @X.LINK I don't know if I understand so I should press `c` to enter the GRUB terminal in boot (the count down screen) or should I press `e` to type single in to the selected kernel? (for the document you give)

Comment: If you can select the kernel to use, just highlight it then press `a` like the tutorial said to append `single`. Please choose the oldest kernel you have though.

Comment: @X.LINK [Here is](https://3l6qig.bn1304.livefilestore.com/y4mCL2KUdoMbdpYNL_UmrzhcAPFUS8D78rfcJXyLQpu72bYh0HdXIS49G_OUqWNwdhRbb6swO-yuBWmEDX0J-vG9GhNBY3Pxopm4mLBb60gdG8_Fk_4YkpVALvZB0oWdrhCuYOGp-trVEJZqzyF-_QKwbfdQQQUfwK4bYdyWdzhXrBatrkmVjkO9CfT6RGEAbHBr-Styf6GF7txXipV1IXi5w/F69C6D96-1A83-428E-BDBA-5126AC4684F7.png?psid=1) the screenshot of the view I see after boot and pressing `a` doesn't do anything.

Comment: Ok, just follow this tutorial instead: https://www.tecmint.com/boot-into-single-user-mode-in-centos-7/

Comment: @X.LINK So I can access the emergency terminal now and what command should I type?

Comment: `df` should do it.

Comment: @X.LINK I typed "df" and it said "df: command not found"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72587/discussion-between-x-link-and-munucial).